# Vim: different tabstop for different columns

Tags: vim, tabular

I have some text file containing datas (like cvs) and formatted with tabs, but the columns doesn't have all the same size.

The default format in vim will be:

```
int1    longvalue1       string1
int2    anotherlongvalue2       string2
```

Can vim use diffent tabstops for different columns? The display would be

```
int1  longvalue1         string1
int2  anotherlongvalue2  string2
```

Comment: The [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align) plugin is ideal for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature (when done automatically by the editor) is commonly called [*Elastic tabstop*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_tabstop). Such patches have been floated for inclusion in Vim (e.g. see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/6b1db9723c62d157/309196dca2836eb5)), but they are far from getting included in Vim (and there's little progress).

As workarounds, you can either `:set ts` to a large value (causing huge gaps, though), or use a plugin like [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294) or [Tabular - Vim script for text filtering and alignment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464) to convert the Tabs to an appropritate amount of whitespace (maybe temporarily; convert back on `:write`).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ingo, the plugin Align is what I need. I want replace the `<tab>` symbols and the plugin do not replace these boundaries (the typical boudary is `=` and should not be replaced).

I therefore have created a function to replace them:

```
" :DoAlign command to format the text as an array by replacing the <tabs>.
" Requires the Align-plugin
fun! DoAlignFunction()
 %s#\t#==motiv==#g
 %Align
 %s#==motiv==##g
endfunction

command! DoAlign call DoAlignFunction()
```

So I can (without selecting any text) replace all my tabs with `:DoAlign`